# How to put Flag on a column?

Tags: sql, database

I am working on something where i have a table C with two columns Ndc and Price. All i care about the price field. it shows invalid values like 0, Null, negative. there is a left join between two tables A and B and i am getting table C from that. so Ndc values are matching and unmatching from both the tables but for that values it shows all invalid Price fields. How can i put flag on Ndc to show the unmatching Ndc Values?

Appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a case statement like this

```
select case when isnull(price, 0) <= 0 then 0 else 1 end as validprice
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you posted the SQL you have so far. It's possible that you might be able to accomplish this with an [outer join](http://infogoal.com/sql/sql-outer-join.htm) and use the rows where the value is null.